# How to Save file in database instead of upload in server media folder ,using models.FileField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-database

I want to save a file in database instead of uploading it to a server media file and save URL in Database, I want directly save file in the Database.

Right now I am doing this:

**model.py:**

```
File = models.FileField(upload_to='CSR/', null=True , blank = True)
```

**template.html:**

```
<td> {{certificate.File.url}} </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Django supports `BinaryField` which lets you store binary data in the database.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/) state:

> **Abusing BinaryField**
>
> Although you might think about storing files in the database, consider that it is bad design in 99% of the cases. This field is not a replacement for proper static files handling.

If you do not want to store files into the filesystem of your webserver, you can use the [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library which provides options for Amazon S3, DigitalOcean and more.